# Mapping a single parent column table to multiple columns of a child table using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, orm

I am trying to map a single parent primary key to multiple child foreign keys. I have a User table which holds users of different types e.g their are users of type admin, type worker, and type client. I then have a child table called job. A single job record holds reference to an admin, worker, and client primary keys. I tried mapping this sinario in hibernate but hibernate gave me an error saying I cannot map a single column to multiple columns. I have attached an email of my table design. [image]

Comment: After thinking it through.  I saw that I could have separate tables for each type of user. That would not be possible as there are many other tables that reference the user table, it would affect the design of the database badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the adminId, workerId and clientId references in your Job POJO, and then configure 3 many-to-one tags as properties of it, all referring to the same table. I think this would work, but I cannot test it right now. Can you post the XML you tried to use, or the Java code, if you were using annotations? Even better, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: On the user xml mapping I have the following `<one-to-many name="jobL" mapped-by="admin" fetch="LAZY"
                         target-entity="za.co.studentfixit.domain.entities.Job"  /> ` and on the job xml job mapping I have the following `<many-to-one name="admin">
                <join-column name="userId"/>
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="client">
                <join-column name="userId"/>
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="worker">
                <join-column name="userId"/>
            </many-to-one>` @Dev_Urandom

Comment: What you are suggestion I believe is exactly what I tried doing but Hibernate gave me errors, saying I cannot have multiple columns referencing the same column @Dev_Urandom